# Default validation for ChangePassword control in ASP webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using the ASP ChangePassword control to assist users with changing their passwords, I've noticed that some passwords would not change when I filled out the form then clicked 'Change Password' this was because they did not contain at least 1 non-alpha-numeric character, I think this is the default behaviour.

So I have added the following:

```
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
                                ID="ProgrammaticID"
                                ControlToValidate="NewPassword"
                                ValidationExpression='^[a-zA-Z]\w{3,14}$'
                                ErrorMessage="The password's first character must be a letter, it must contain at least 4 characters and no more than 15 characters and no characters other than letters, numbers and the underscore may be used"
                                Text="The password's first character must be a letter, it must contain at least 4 characters and no more than 15 characters and no characters other than letters, numbers and the underscore may be used"
                                ForeColor="red"
                                BackColor="white"
                                runat="server"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The validation is working as expected now on the actual pop-up form, however, how do I change the default validation that the actual control works with to match what I want, not what the control wants?

I cannot find anything in the properties, and I am guessing what the default rules are, my RegularExpressionValidator is useless until I can make the control follow these rules rather than submitting even though the validation did not pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong place. You don't need Regular Expression to change that behavior. I believe it is set in the web.config

**minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"**

```
<membership>
      <providers>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"     

        minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" 
        ... />
      </providers>

</membership>
```